# OBIEE -- Header is Not displaying while open the dashboard

Tags: oracle, obiee

Can any one help on this?
1)When I open the dashboard the Header and banner part is totally disabled.
i used Developer tool to find  the error.
i got some error message like

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL  ---->  in header.js:1.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'alertsNode' of undefined .
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'FavoriteHeaderMenu' of undefined.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'registerSkipToContentEltFinder' of undefined.
```

Comment: Which web browser, which version of OBIEE?

Comment: Are you flipping between older and newer versions of OBIEE in the same browser?